# Python: Cross-platform solution to detect physical non-HT CPUs?

Tags: python, windows, linux, multiprocessing

I'm trying to detect the number of non-HyperThreading cores on a machine using a cross-platform method.

Multiprocessing's [cpu_count](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/60f7719c0415/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py#l108) only detects the total number of processors, and I can grep /proc/cpuinfo on Linux machines to find the answer. However, I'm looking for a Windows solution.

This newsgroup [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nzpug/_5sFW9BEMQ4) helped a little, but I still haven't found the answer.

Comment: I can't see the correlation with python :)

Comment: I'm looking for a cross-platform solution in Python language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Tim Golden's WMI bindings to access wmi information about CPUs on Windows. See [Tim's wmi module cookbook](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html). You probabably want to use the `Win32_Processor` class -- see 
[the Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note that in the *remarks* section the Microsoft documentation states:

> > To determine if hyperthreading is enabled for the processor, compare NumberOfLogicalProcessors and NumberOfCores. If hyperthreading is enabled in the BIOS for the processor, then NumberOfCores is less than NumberOfLogicalProcessors. For example, a dual-processor system that contains two processors enabled for hyperthreading can run four threads or programs or simultaneously. In this case, NumberOfCores is 2 and NumberOfLogicalProcessors is 4.

[Dag Wieer's](http://dag.wieers.com/blog/is-hyper-threading-enabled-on-a-linux-system) blog shows a way of extracting hyperthreading info from `/proc/cpuinfo` on Linux.

I think, if the output of the first and second lines of

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep 'physical|processor' | grep -v sizes | \
                    tail -n2 | cut -d : -f 2`
```

is different, hyperthreading is enabled.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `egrep 'physical|processor'` returns 3 on my i7 (2 cores + HT), but cpu cores seems to always return physical cores.

Comment: Oh -- that's interesting. It doesn't do that on my i5 laptop. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

platform independent and in python standard library:

> psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)

Comment: this is *not* is the python standard library, but still the best answer in my opinion

Comment: This is the more easy & solid recipe than others.

Answer (score 0):

For a platform-independent method, see the python bindings to hwloc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hwloc
topology = hwloc.Topology()
topology.load()
print topology.get_nbobjs_by_type(hwloc.OBJ_CORE)
```

hwloc is designed to be portable across OSes and architectures.