# python how to find out whether hyperthreading is enabled

Tags: python, multiprocessing, hyperthreading

I have Intel i7-2600K quadcore, with hyperthreading enabled on Ubuntu 12.04. I know that I can find out how many cores I have in Python with `import multiprocessing; multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, but that gives me 8 because I have hyperthreading enabled on 4 physical cores. I'm rather interested in finding out how many physical cores I have. Is there a way to do that in Python? Alternatively, is there a way of finding out in Python whether hyperthreading is enabled? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Cross-platform solution to detect physical non-HT CPUs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152173/python-cross-platform-solution-to-detect-physical-non-ht-cpus)

Comment: are you on linux or windows? The answer will be different, I don't think there exists a platform independent solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://archive.richweb.com/cpu_info, determining a cpu hyperthreading a bit complicated, but still useful.

Note that method is linux-specific.

Comment: OK that's helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

To get hyperthreading information on the mac, you can use:

```
os.popen('sysctl hw').readlines()[1:20]
```

and compare the `'hw.activecpu'` value to the `'hw.physicalcpu'` value, the former being the number of cpus including hyperthreading. Or you could just compare `'hw.physicalcpu'` with the value returned from `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.

On linux you could do something similar using:

```
os.popen('lscpu').readlines()
```

and multiply the `'Socket(s)'` value and the `'Core(s) per socket'` value to get the number of physical cpus.  Again, you could check this number against `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.

I dont use Windows, so I cant help you there, but it seems like others have some ideas in this direction

An example related to this can be found here [hardware_info()](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/master/qutip/hardware_info.py).

Comment: lscpu -p gives comma separated output

Answer (score 1):

On windows, to see if hyperthreading is enbabled you can do some WMI magic with [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from win32com.client import GetObject

winmgmts_root = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
cpus = winmgmts_root.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
for cpu in cpus:
    print('on "{}", hyperthreading is '.format(cpu.DeviceID), end='') 
    if cpu.NumberOfCores < cpu.NumberOfLogicalProcessors:
        print('active')
    else:
        print('inactive')
```

On my machine, the output is:

> on "CPU0", hyperthreading is active

See more [info at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describing what can be fetched from the Win32_Processor class.

Answer (score 0):

> On windows, to see if hyperthreading is enbabled you can do some WMI magic with pywin32:

**Wrong idea!** On my Core2Due (without any hyperthrating) it gives same output:

```
<on "CPU0", hyperthreading is active>
```

I think you must change string in code to:

```
if cpu.NumberOfCores < cpu.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

(no LowerOrEqual just Lower)